# How can I get/calculate simulink bldc parameters

Tags: motor, simulation, brushless-dc-motor, matlab, simulink

I tried to get the parameters for a bldc simulation https://de.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ref/brushlessdcmotor.html

I tried to find a similar motor to the I need (500 W, 20-25 Nm, geared bldc)
However I can't get either flux linkage or the rotor-induced back emf, the options there.

Could you help me how can I get the data needed from a table like this?
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Mathematical-Modeling-of-Permanent-Magnet-Brushless-Shetty-Subramonium/7bd32a8ef2049ede79ef2eb6af7609d4ca5701dd/figure/0
table1

Any help or literature is appreciated.

Comment: I'm quite new to stack exchange, is there something I can do to improve my question?

Comment: how to improve the question? unsure at the moment... what can be done is a bit of patience. less than 14minutes before querying a response is a bit... we are volunteer's of a small stackexchange

Comment: So far I found this link
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110557/calculating-back-emf-from-torque-constant
It seems assuming blcd with trapezoidal back-emf
toque constant is less than or equals with the back-emf constant

According to this link
https://www.motioncontroltips.com/faq-difference-between-torque-back-emf-motor-constant/
Emf = emf constant * angular velocity

Could someone confirm my understanding?